# How to parse the resume data?

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I have applied this code to extract data from Resume by using python, but my code isn't working. My objective is to parse the resume or extract data from resume, then applied algorithm to predict the label. My target is to "Ranking the candidate resume based on the skills and their resume content" in python.

Can anybody help me regarding this?

```sh
pip install python-docx
pip install docx
pip install pyresparser
```

```py
from pyresparser import ResumeParser

import os

from docx import Document

# file format should be in .txt, .pdf, .docx
filed= input()

# below line is used to read the file from this path **D:/CV/Updated_CV.docx**

try:
    doc= Document()
    with open(filed,'r') as file:
        doc.add_paragraph(file.read())
        doc.save("text.docx")
        data= ResumeParser('text.docx').get_extracted_data()
        print(data['Skills'])
except:
        data= ResumeParser(filed).get_extracted_data() 
        print(data['Skills'])
```

I think the way I defined path is not correct **D:/CV/Updated_CV.docx**

Comment: Your path looks okay. Can you strip down your program so that it's only got the `with open` line and not any of the document processing?  Just `print('Success')` or something in that block.  I suspect your exception is happening during the read.  Failing that, double check that you have access to the d: drive (i.e., it's not unplugged or a network share.

Comment: Were you able to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

just put all your CVs in the same folder which has your .ipynb file. then just enter the pdf name with the .pdf extension. (Ex: "Updated_CV.docx") then press enter. hope this would work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).